# Checking for duplicates in VEINS

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++, veins, sumo

I am new to Veins and trying to implement a mechanism to detect if the WSM packet was received before. I am using the "psid" as the main variable to identify the packet - is it correct?

Will this type of code work? :

```
bool MyVeinsApp::msgReceivedBefore(int psid){
  /*
  This function will be used to determine if the message was received before
  and should be discarded or processed further
  */

  if(msg_log.find(psid) == msg_log.end()){
     return false
  }
  else {
     return true;
  }

}
```

Here msg.log is a C++ data structure storing WSMs based on psid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The psid only is an identifier for the service you are using (see [WaveShortMessage.msg](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/messages/WaveShortMessage.msg)) and therefore not unique among messages of the same service. To distinguish between messages you need a unique message identifier.

A simple approach would be to use the [id](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp4/api/classcModule.html#a592b754c94045c707e4f5155f00c18f2) which every module in OMNeT++ gets:

```
msg->getId()
```

**UPDATE**: Please note that this id also is unique among all messages with the same content (see comment down below).

Comment: This is not 100% correct. As Veins internally duplicates messages, every car receives a message with a different id - although the message in reality is the same broadcast.
Therefore, to make this work, you probably need to extend your message with a unique identifier and assign a value using `getUniqueNumber()` from the simulation environment.